# Question about linear operator continuity

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator, $X,Y$ normed spaces.

Show that a linear operator is continuous (bounded) if for every sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$ in $X$ has a bounded image $Ax_n$ in $Y$.

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $A:X\to Y$ be a linear map. Then $A$ is bounded if
and only if there exists $\| A\| \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\| Ax\| \leq \| A\|$ for
any $x\in X$ with $\| x\|=1$. Hence, $A$ is unbounded if and only if for any $c>0$ there
exists $x\in X$ with $\| x\|=1$ such that $\| Ax\|\geq c$.

Assume that $A$ has the following property: if $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ is a
sequence which converges to $0$, then $\{ Ax_n;\, n\in {\mathbb N}\}$ is a bounded subset 
of $Y$. Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $A$ is unbounded. Then for any $n\in {\mathbb N}$ there exists $z_n\in X$ with $\| z_n\|=1$ such that $\| Az_n\| \geq n^2$. Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}z_n$ ($\forall n\in {\mathbb N}$). Then 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\| x_n\|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0,$$
i.e., the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$. However, $\{ Ax_n;\, n\in {\mathbb N}\}$ is not a bounded subset of $Y$ since $\| A x_n\|=\frac{1}{n}\| A z_n\|\geq n$.